# Create array inside foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello everything is fine?

I have a foreach that is returning two dates from the database and converting to hours, minutes and seconds.

The minutes are coming more than 1 which is normal, since my SELECT uses WHERE with LIKE.

But I can't create an array to add the minutes that are returning in quantity.

Example: Returns 4 values 45, I want to insert in an array to add the total minutes.

see my code:

```
$select_consulta_profissional_query = "SELECT * FROM queries
                                        WHERE professional like :professional";
$select_consulta_profissional = $pdo->prepare($select_consulta_profissional_query);
$select_consulta_profissional->execute([':profissional' => $name]);

$qty_hours_professional = $select_consulta_profissional->rowCount();

$horaras_profissional = $select_consulta_profissional->fetchAll();
```

//RETURNS THE HOUR MINUTES AND SECONDS BETWEEN THE QUERY DATES and formatted

```
foreach ($professional_hours as $row_professional_hours) {

     $start_date = $row_professional_time['1'];
     $final_date = $row_professional_time['2'];

     $start_date_convert = strtotime($start_date);
     $data_final_convert = strtotime($data_final);

     $difference = $data_final_convert - $data_inicio_convert;
    
     $hours = intval($difference / 3600);
     $minutes = doubleval(($difference % 3600) / 60);
     $seconds = doubleval($difference % 60);

     $consumed_time = $hours . ":" . $minutes . ":" . $seconds;

     echo $minutes;
}
```

Can you help me please?

List two database dates and find out how many hours, minutes and seconds they are different from each other

Comment: Have you considered using the MySQL builtin function `TIMEDIFF()` instead of calculating the difference in PHP? Read about this function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: Hello.

I think it might work.

Can I save the result of the diff in a MYSQL table?

Comment: You can use the function as an expression, in a variety of ways to set a value in a column. That's pretty ordinary SQL, covered in any tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I can't adjust but I'll research better, thanks for the help.